# Do not autocomplete with company if point is behind a possible completion

Tags: completion, company-mode

In other words, let point be denoted by `^`, if I first type `asarray`, then move point to the beginning of the word, and type `scipy.`, i.e., end up with `scipy.^asarray`, don't show possible completions for `scipy.` (`asarray` is already a completion). If `asarray` were incomplete, e.g., `asar`, then show possible completions for `asar`. At the moment, it shows all completions as though nothing were after point.

Is there an easy way to handle this?

Comment: That's up to the backend's author. They chose the unusual behavior here, looks like.

Comment: @Dmitry, the backend returns a list of completions, so company could narrow that list depending on what's ahead of point, no? Or is that list capped by the backend?

Comment: The current approach is to avoid suggesting completions when point is before a word.